# Is there a way of deleting duplicates more refined than fdupes -rdN?

Tags: files, disk-usage, fdupes

Recently I have the need to delete a lot of duplicates. I am merging three or four filesystems, and I want the space to be used economically. At first, `fdupes` seemed like it was the best tool for the job, but I am increasingly running into limitations.

Consider the command `fdupes -rdN somedirectory/`. This makes a hash of all of the files in the subdirectories of somedirectory.

And when it encounters duplicates, it deletes them, so that there is only one copy of everything.

But what if I want to keep `somedirectory/subdirectory1/somefile` and there are, in fact, four duplicates, and the program encounters one of the duplicates first? Then it deletes `somedirectory/subdirectory1/somefile`, which I don't want.

I want to be able to specify, somehow, which duplicates to keep. And so far, none of the standard programs for dealing with duplicates (duff, FSLint) seem to allow automation of that kind of behavior. I'd prefer not to roll my own, so that's why I'm asking this question.

I'd like to be able to write something like

```
killdupes -rdN --keep=filesin,somedirectories,separated,by,commas somedirectory/
```

Comment: I was looking for the same thing and I found this http://superuser.com/a/561207/218922

Answer (score 12):

While the functionality you seek is not available in stock `fdupes`, I forked `fdupes` [(my fork is called `jdupes`)](https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes) and added some features that can solve this problem under certain circumstances. For example, in the stated case where you wish to keep `somedirectory/subdirectory1/somefile` when auto-deleting duplicates (the `d` and `N` switches together) and there are no separate files immediately beneath `somedirectory`, `jdupes` can be fed each immediate subdirectory path with `subdirectory1` first and the `-O` switch (which sorts files by command-line parameter order first):

`jdupes -rdNO somedirectory/subdirectory1 somedirectory/subdirectory2 somedirectory/subdirectory3`

This will auto-delete all but one file in a duplicate set and will guarantee that if the set contains a file in `somedirectory/subdirectory1` it will be the first, thereby automatically becoming the preserved file in the set. There are still glaring limits to this approach such as the fact that another duplicate in `somedirectory/subdirectory1` might be preserved instead of the one you wanted to keep, but in a good number of cases like yours, the `jdupes` parameter order option as a workaround is good enough.

In the near future, I plan to add a filtering system to `jdupes` that will enable a huge amount of control over inclusion/exclusion of files, preservation for `-N` actions, and application of such "filter stacks" on either a global or per-parameter basis. This feature is sorely needed; I envision something like this to "auto-delete non-zero duplicates recursively BUT always preserve `somedirectory/subdirectory1/somefile` as-is":

`jdupes -rdN --filter=preserve:somedirectory/subdirectory1/somefile somedirectory/`

**UPDATE (2022-03-01):** Take a look at the `-X` extended filter options added in 2020. It's not exactly what you want, but the `nostr` and `onlystr` filters let you specify substrings within a full path to ignore or require.

Comment: Note that `-n` mentioned in this answer is no longer available. "The -n/--no-empty option was removed for safety. Matching zero-length files as duplicates now requires explicit use of the -z/--zero-match option instead." (jdupes is indeed great. Thanks, Jody!)

Comment: I updated the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I didn't see this one anywhere else: Say what you want is this. You have /mnt/folder-tree-1  /mnt/folder-tree-2. You don't want to remove every dupe, but if a file exists in tree-2, and an identical file exists in tree-1 with the exact same path and name, remove it from tree-2.

Warning: this quite terse and if you try to copy-paste this with limited shell skills, be careful.

```
fdupes -rn /mnt/folder-tree-1/ /mnt/folder-tree-2/ > dupes-all.txt

fgrep /mnt/folder-tree-1/ dupes-all.txt | while read line
do
if grep -q "`echo $line | sed -e 's|^/mnt/folder-tree-1/|/mnt/folder-tree-2/|'`" dupes-all.txt
then
    echo rm \"$(echo $line | sed -e 's|^/mnt/folder-tree-1/|/mnt/folder-tree-2//|')\"
fi
done > rm-v2-dupes.sh
```

Or all on one line:

```
fdupes -rn /mnt/folder-tree-1/ /mnt/folder-tree-2/ > dupes-all.txt; fgrep /mnt/folder-tree-1/ dupes-all.txt | while read line; do if grep -q "`echo $line | sed -e 's|^/mnt/folder-tree-1/|/mnt/folder-tree-2/|'`" dupes-all.txt; then echo rm \"$(echo $line | sed -e 's|^/mnt/folder-tree-1/|/mnt/folder-tree-2/|')\"; fi; done > rm-v2-dupes.sh
```

Afterwards, inspect and execute rm-v2-dupes.sh

Answer (score 4):

What about hardlinking the duplicate files together? That way the space is only used once, but they still exist in all the paths. The catch with this is that hardlinked files should be modified in place (they should only be modified deleting the file and recreating it with the new content). The other approach is to symlink the files together, although you have the same issue of deciding which the "primary" file is. This could be done with the following script (although note that this doesn't handle filenames containing spaces).

```
fdupes --quiet --recurse --sameline somedirectory/ | while read SOURCE DESTS; do
    for DEST in $DESTS; do
        ln -f $SOURCE $DEST
    done
done
```

Comment: Using [`jdupes`](https://github.org/jbruchon/jdupes) instead of `fdupes` you can simply go `jdupes -nrL somedirectory/` which is massively quicker.

Comment: Typo in the link to jdupes. Convenience link: https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question. If you have many duplicates `fdupes /my/directory/ -rdN` keeps the file with the oldest modify date, or if several files have the same modify date, then the one found first.

If the modify date is not important to you, you can `touch` the files in the directory you want to keep. If you choose to `touch` them with the current date and time then
`fdupes -rdNi` will keep the ones with the current date. Or you can `touch` the keep files with a date earlier than that of the ones you want deleted and use `fdupes -rdN` as normal.

If you need to keep the modify date, then you will need to use one of the other methods.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a twist to a previous answer.  I've used the following code multiple times, slightly modifying a previous answer with a simple `| grep` to isolate the folder I want to delete from.

```
`fdupes -r -n -S /directory | grep /delete-from-directory | sed -r "s/^/rm \"/" | sed -r "s/$/\"/" >remove-duplicate-files.sh`
```

Again, this will create a sh file to delete all files listed, no commented lines.  Of course you can still edit the file to comment out specific lines/files you want to keep.

Another hint for large directories is to run fdupes to a txt file, then experiment with `| grep` and `| sed` until I get the result I want.

```
`fdupes -r -n -S /directory > duplicate-files.txt`
`cat duplicate-files.txt | grep /delete-from-directory | sed -r "s/^/rm \"/" | sed -r "s/$/\"/" >remove-duplicate-files.sh`
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use [`sed`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) to create a shell file that will contain commented out commands to delete each of your duplicate files:**

```
fdupes -r -n -S /directory | sed -r "s/^/#rm \"/" | sed -r "s/$/\"/" >remove-duplicate-files.sh
```

The resulting **`remove-duplicate-files.sh`** file that we've just created will have each line commented out. Uncomment the files you want to delete. Then run **`sh remove-duplicate-files.sh`**. Voila!

***UPDATE***

**Well, if you don't want to delete files only in certain directories, it's as simple as this**:

```
fdupes -S /directory|sed '/^$/d' |sed -r "s/^[0-9]/#&/" > duple_list

python exclude_duplicates.py -f /path/to/dupe_list --delimiter='#' --keep=/full/path/to/protected/directory1,/full/path/to/protected/directory2\ with\ spaces\ in\ path >remove-duplicate-files-keep-protected.sh
```

Where `exclude_duplicates.py` is:

```py
#/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# exclude_duplicates.py
"""
THE SCRIPT DOESN'T DELETE ANYTHING, IT ONLY GENERATES TEXT OUTPUT.
Provided a list of duplicates, such as fdupes or fslint output,
generate a bash script that will have all duplicates in protected
directories commented out. If none of the protected duplicates are
found in a set of the same files, select a random unprotected
duplicate for preserving.
Each path to a file will be transformed to an `rm "path"` string which
will be printed to standard output.     
"""

from optparse import OptionParser
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-k", "--keep", dest="keep",
    help="""List of directories which you want to keep, separated by commas. \
        EXAMPLE: exclude_duplicates.py --keep /path/to/directory1,/path/to/directory\ with\ space\ in\ path2""",
    metavar="keep"
)
parser.add_option("-d", "--delimiter", dest="delimiter",
    help="Delimiter of duplicate file groups", metavar="delimiter"
)
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="file",
    help="List of duplicate file groups, separated by delimiter, for example, fdupes or fslint output.", metavar="file"
)

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
directories_to_keep = options.keep.split(',')
file = options.file
delimiter = options.delimiter

pretty_line = '\n#' + '-' * 35
print '#/bin/bash'
print '#I will protect files in these directories:\n'
for d in directories_to_keep:
    print '# ' + d
print pretty_line

protected_set = set()
group_set = set()

def clean_set(group_set, protected_set, delimiter_line):
    not_protected_set = group_set - protected_set
    while not_protected_set:
        if len(not_protected_set) == 1 and len(protected_set) == 0:
            print '#randomly selected duplicate to keep:\n#rm "%s"' % not_protected_set.pop().strip('\n')
        else:
            print 'rm "%s"' % not_protected_set.pop().strip('\n')
    for i in protected_set: print '#excluded file in protected directory:\n#rm "%s"' % i.strip('\n')
    print '\n#%s' % delimiter_line
file = open(file, 'r')
for line in file.readlines():
    if line.startswith(delimiter):
        clean_set(group_set, protected_set, line)
        group_set, protected_set = set(), set()
    else:
        group_set = group_set|{line}
        for d in directories_to_keep:
            if line.startswith(d): protected_set = protected_set|{line}
else:
    if line: clean_set(group_set, protected_set, line)
```

The resulting **`remove-duplicate-files-keep-protected.sh`** file that we've just created will have all files from protected directories commented out. Open this file in your favorite text editor, check that everything is OK. Then run it. Voila (sic)!

Comment: i thought of this, but it's not automated enough. stupidly, i caused data loss with this method when dealing with duplicates spaced across multiple filesystems... there's no way to assign a priority, given the output of fdupes. basically i would have had to trawl through 10000 files by hand in order to prevent that data loss... so, no thanks... in fact, that data loss is the very reason i asked this question.

Comment: @ixtmixilix, well, manual method is dependent on user attentiveness, here's nothing new. If you want something more automated, checkout an updated answer above.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

DUPE_SEARCH_DIR=somedir/
PREFERRED_DIRS=("somedir/subdir1" "somedir/subdir2")
DUPE_FILE=/tmp/`basename $0`_found-duplicates

delete_dupes() {
    while read line ; do
        if [ -n "$line" ] ; then
            matched=false
            for pdir in "${PREFERRED_DIRS[@]}" ; do
                if [[ $line == $pdir/* ]] ; then
                    matched=true
                    break
                fi
            done
            if ! $matched ; then
                rm -v "$line"
            fi
        fi
    done < "$DUPE_FILE"
}

cleanup() {
    rm -f $DUPE_FILE
}

trap cleanup EXIT

# get rid of normal dupes, preserve first & preserve preferred
fdupes -rf "$DUPE_SEARCH_DIR" > $DUPE_FILE
delete_dupes

# get rid of preserve dupes, preserve preferred
fdupes -r "$DUPE_SEARCH_DIR" > "$DUPE_FILE"
delete_dupes
```

Answer (score 1):

As of the Apple Filesystem (APFS), another solution is to to keep the files, deduplicate them, and have no impact on disk use. See [Replace existing duplicate files on APFS with clones](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316435/replace-existing-duplicate-files-on-apfs-with-clones/379536)

Answer (score 0):

Only delete files from `back` directory

```
jdupes -r orig back | grep "^back" | xargs rm
```